# autocomplete does not get populate after entering text from selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-api

The website I am testing for has a textbox to enter location. When I enter a character, Google API sends the list of locations matching this character below the textbox. here is the [snapshot of autocomplete options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT5jh.jpg)

I am trying to automate this scenario in selenium. But the problem is when I do textbox.sendkeys("text"), the populating the locations list from Google API does not happen.

I have tried implicit and explicit wait, with timer upto 200s, still it didn't work. I tried, click() before sendkeys(), KEYS.Arrow_down after sendkeys() and also mouseclick. But it still doesn't seem to work.
Please provide your suggestions.

Here is my test code:

```
public void add_inv() throws Exception{
        commands.implicitwait(driver);
        Inventory.btn_addinventory(driver).click();
        Inventory.btn_addlocation(driver).click();
        Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).click();
        commands.implicitwait(driver);
        Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).click();
        Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).sendKeys("bangalore", Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        commands.setDefaultTimeout(100);
        commands.implicitwait(driver);
        String loctext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[1]/span[3]")).getText();
        System.out.println("loctext: "+loctext);
}
```

Comment: Is the application available for public view so that we can try it out?

Comment: I am sorry, right now on staging hence on local.

Comment: Is it happening always or once upon?

Comment: happening always..

Answer (score 0):

try with action class as given below.

```
public void add_inv() throws Exception{
        commands.implicitwait(driver);
        Inventory.btn_addinventory(driver).click();
        Inventory.btn_addlocation(driver).click();
        Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).click();
        commands.implicitwait(driver);
        Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).click();
        //Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).sendKeys("bangalore", Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver),"bangalore").perform();
        String loctext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[1]/span[3]")).getText();
        System.out.println("loctext: "+loctext);
}
```

Comment: I tried action class as you suggested, doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Please check your locator for input box. Otherwise share the HTML code.

Comment: Here it is:<input id="locationAddName" class="ng-pending ng-touched ng-dirty ng-empty" type="text" ng-change="inventorySearchChng('location')" valid-method="submit-only" validator="required" ng-model="newLocation.name" name="locationName" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" style=""/>

Comment: Please try this. Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).sendKeys("bangalore");
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).getAttribute("ng-change"));

Comment: tried this. it gives this error:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: inventorySearchChng is not defined

Comment: Something strange happened now, I tried following code and it worked.
Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).sendKeys("location");
Thread.sleep(2000);
Inventory.txt_locAddr(driver).sendKeys("location");

But when I do sendkeys once after sleep, it doesn't work.

Comment: It worked, Thread.sleep(5000) after click(), and then do sendkeys()

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Edge browser. The solution is to Click the searchtext box and then send keys.

```
driver.click();// on the search box
Driver.sendkeys("ABC").
```

For me the tabs or any keys after the sendkeys had not worked.
Thanks